# Inconsistent data when geo-querying from Firebase Realtime Database in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

```js
const [location, setLocation] = useState<any>()
  const userId = '1234'

  const updateUserLocation = async (position: any) => {
    const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords
    await database()
      .ref(`usersLocations/${userId}`)
      .set(encodeLocationObject({ latitude, longitude }))
    console.log('location updated')
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    let watchId: number

    const handleLocationChange = async (position: any) => {
      setLocation(position)
      await updateUserLocation(position)

      setTimeout(async () => {
        const nearbyUsers = await findNearbyUsers(position)
        console.log(nearbyUsers)
      }, 5000)
    }

    const startWatchingLocation = async () => {
      watchId = Geolocation.watchPosition(
        handleLocationChange,
        error => {
          Alert.alert(`Error getting location: ${error.message}`)
        },
        {
          enableHighAccuracy: true,
          distanceFilter: 10,
        },
      )
    }

    startWatchingLocation()

    return () => {
      Geolocation.clearWatch(watchId)
    }
  }, [])
```

```js
export const findNearbyUsers = async (userLocation: GeoPosition) => {
  try {
    const {latitude, longitude} = userLocation.coords
    const geohash = ngeohash.encode(latitude, longitude)

    const RADIUS = USER_DISCOVER_RANGE + 50
    const center = ngeohash.decode(geohash)
    const latPerMeter = 1 / 111111
    const lonPerMeter = Math.abs(Math.cos(center.latitude) * latPerMeter)

    const latMin = center.latitude - latPerMeter * RADIUS
    const latMax = center.latitude + latPerMeter * RADIUS
    const lonMin = center.longitude - lonPerMeter * RADIUS
    const lonMax = center.longitude + lonPerMeter * RADIUS

    const dbRef = database()
      .ref('usersLocations')
      .orderByChild('g')
      .startAt(ngeohash.encode(latMin, lonMin))
      .endAt(ngeohash.encode(latMax, lonMax))

    const users = (await dbRef.once('value')).val()
    const currentUserID = '123'
    let nearbyUsers: Array<suggestedUser> = []

    console.log(Object.keys(users));
    

    for (let userID of Object.keys(users)) {
      if (userID !== currentUserID) {
        const otherLocation = users[userID].l
        // console.log({latitude, longitude}, otherLocation)
        const distance = getDistance({latitude, longitude}, otherLocation)
        console.log(userID, distance);
        
        if (distance < 100) {
          nearbyUsers.push({distance, id: userID})
        }
      }
    }

    // console.log('user range', USER_DISCOVER_RANGE)

    // if (users) {
    //   Object.keys(users).forEach(userID => {})
    // }

    dbRef.off('value')
    return nearbyUsers
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    throw error
  }
}
```

[image: Console log output]

I have this code in my React Native app, that sets the user location and queries for nearby users. The problem is that when querying it returns inconsistent data first time it return less than it should, the next time after it returns the correct result.

I tried geofire-js but since it doesn't work with the '@react-native-firebase/database', due to the large number of reads/writes, I can't use Firestore either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach you're taking here won't work:

```
const latMin = center.latitude - latPerMeter * RADIUS
const latMax = center.latitude + latPerMeter * RADIUS
const lonMin = center.longitude - lonPerMeter * RADIUS
const lonMax = center.longitude + lonPerMeter * RADIUS

const dbRef = database()
  .ref('usersLocations')
  .orderByChild('g')
  .startAt(ngeohash.encode(latMin, lonMin))
  .endAt(ngeohash.encode(latMax, lonMax))
```

While geohash values that are similar to each other are guaranteed to be close to each other, the inverse is not true: there is no guarantee that points that are close to each will have similar geohash values.

Have a look at this range for example:
[image]

While `9r0`, `9r1`, `9r2` and `9r3` are all close to each both geographically and alphabetically, `9pp` is also close geographically - yet not alphabetically.

For this reason you need to query multiple ranges of geohashes for a single geoquery, up to 9 iirc but typically somewhere between 4 and 6. That's why the GeoFire libraries return a list of geohash bounds, as you can also see in this code snippet: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries#web_2

My recommendation is to look at that [`geohashQueryBounds` function of the geofire-common library](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/blob/b5bc3a74b91a966764d1e7c350e1e51e51cc67f2/packages/geofire-common/src/index.ts#L345) and copy from it what you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, it helped me a lot to improve the app.